# Is there any "reversible hashtable" like data structure?

Tags: data-structures

Imagine an array that associate numbers and words. Exactly one number for one word and vice versa.

```
dic = [0: 'food', 
 1: 'dinner',
 2.5: 'breakfast',
  ...]
```

Now I want to access `dic[0]` and get `food` and `something['food']` and get `0`. Is there any kind of reversible hashtable in the wild ? As far as I know only doing a duplicate can solve this problem.

Comment: Check out bimaps: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is generally done by combining two maps. Modifications are a bit tricky, because they have to maintain the one-to-one rule.

Let's start with a class for finite maps, and a couple sample instances for `containers` types:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE
      FunctionalDependencies
    , FlexibleInstances
    , UndecidableInstances
    , GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

module Mappy where
import Prelude hiding (lookup)
-- Example base maps
import qualified Data.Map.Strict as M
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.IntMap.Strict as IM
import Data.IntMap (IntMap)

class Mappy k v m | m -> k v where
  empty :: m
  insert :: k -> v -> m -> m
  delete :: k -> m -> m
  lookup :: k -> m -> Maybe v

instance Ord k => Mappy k a (Map k a) where
  empty = M.empty
  insert = M.insert
  delete = M.delete
  lookup = M.lookup

instance Mappy Int a (IntMap a) where
  empty = IM.empty
  insert = IM.insert
  delete = IM.delete
  lookup = IM.lookup
```

Now we can build our type for bidirectional maps:

```hs
data Bimap m n = Bimap !m !n
instance Show m => Show (Bimap m n) where
  showsPrec p (Bimap m _) = showParen (p > 10) $
    showString "Bimap " . showsPrec 11 m

invert :: Bimap m n -> Bimap n m
invert (Bimap m n) = Bimap n m

instance (Mappy k v kv, Mappy v k vk) => Mappy k v (Bimap kv vk) where
  empty = Bimap empty empty
  insert k v (Bimap kv vk)
    | Just k' <- lookup v vk
    = Bimap (insert k v $ delete k' kv) (insert v k vk)
    | otherwise
    = Bimap (insert k v kv) (insert v k vk)
  delete k m@(Bimap kv vk)
    | Just v <- lookup k kv
    = Bimap (delete k kv) (delete v vk)
    | otherwise
    = m
  lookup k (Bimap kv _) = lookup k kv
```

We can also define some wrappers to make it easier to write our desired map types.

```hs
newtype MapMap k v = MapMap (Bimap (Map k v) (Map v k)) deriving (Show, Mappy k v)
newtype IMM v = IMM (Bimap (IntMap v) (Map v Int)) deriving (Show, Mappy Int v)
```